# What is the minimal size the slit should have in order for an interference pattern to occur?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, interference, diffraction

Consider the single slit experiment. The width of the slit can be given as:
$b= \frac{\lambda}{2} * \frac {1}{\sin(\theta)}  $, where $\theta$ is the angle for the first minimum is.
At which minimal width can we expect interference to take place at the slit?

Can we argument that interference always takes place no matter what length, and it is  a question about if we are able to observe it? Thus, for angles $ \theta> 0,1° $,
if we consider a green laser with $ \lambda = 550\,\mathrm{nm} $ then we will receive for $\theta = 0,1 ° $ a width of $b=1.575 * 10^{-5}\,\mathrm{m}$.

Does my argumentation make sense?

Answer (score 2):

(a) The equation giving the angle of the first (Fraunhofer) diffraction minimum is $$\lambda = b \sin \theta.$$ Your equation has an erroneous factor of 2 (or $\frac 12$) in it.

(b) "Can we argument [argue] that interference always takes place no matter what length, and it is a question about if we are able to observe it?" Yes, if I'm interpreting you correctly. For example, for a slit that is narrower than the wavelength ($b<\lambda$) the interference will be 'less constructive', that is the resultant intensity will decrease, as we increase our viewing angle from 0° to 90°, but it won't become zero, and you might not notice the fall off in intensity (especially if $b$ is less than – let's say – half  $\lambda$).

(c) I assume that you are asking in your last paragraph whether you can determine the width of a slit by measuring the angle $\theta$ of the first minimum for a known wavelength  of light. The answer is that you can, provided that $b>\lambda$.

Comment: Of course, the formula given wouldn't work for $b<\lambda$, would it? Interesting, I've never actually asked myself what would actually happen when the slit-width was smaller than the wavelength, I just assumed that diffraction wouldn't occur. Do you happen to have any references that discuss this?

Comment: @Philip. I haven't found specific discussion of the case $b<\lambda$, but what happens is easily deduced from a treatment of the general case of single slit diffraction by dividing the slit into narrow strips. Jenkins and White (Fundamentals of Optics) gives a straightforward treatment; Hecht.Zajac (Optics) gives a rather more sophisticated analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Concept to solve this problem is **Fresnel Distance**.
Fresnel distance describes the distance that a light beam can travel so that diffraction is significant. This value gives a boundary of Ray Optics and Wave Optics.

It is denoted by $Z_\mathrm{f}$.

$$Z_\mathrm{f} = \frac{a^2}{\lambda}$$

$a$ = aperture of the slit

$\lambda$ = wavelength of incident light

Small slits are good for interference or diffraction, the problem actually is how big can a slit be to observe signification wave behaviour for interference to occur.

So $Z_\mathrm{f}$ solves the problem.

If $d < Z_\mathrm{f}$
then Ray Optics is valid and spreading of wave is insignificant.

If $d > Z_\mathrm{f}$
then Wave Optics is valid and spreading of wave is significant.

$d$ = distance travelled by the wave [either from source to slit or from slit to screen, take whichever is smaller]